# How to merge multiple views into one bitmap

Tags: java, android

I have an image picked from user gallery. I also have a button which generates custom Edit Text, whose value i can drag around a relative Layout. This part of the code works fine, but I was wondering if there was a way I could create a bitmap that captures the screen just as it looks when there is this image picked from the user gallery, the Edit Text value and other parts of the layout that the image did not cover (am using center crop scale type).
As you can see in my SendToDb method, I have already tried using createBitmap but this returns a null value, just an empty screen layout,with neither the image nor the edit text value. Any help on how I can have the new bitmap with both the image and edittext? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!
[Here is a screenshot of the final bitmap I'd like to have. Thanks in advance!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpN5i.jpg)

Here is my xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".CanvasTestActivity">


       <RelativeLayout
           android:id="@+id/imgv"
           android:layout_above="@+id/post"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/select"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="350dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/drag"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </RelativeLayout>


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/editshow"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="11dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_bio" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/post"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:text="Post" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and in the activity

```
public class CanvasTestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button Post;
    private ImageButton selectStory, showet;
    private RelativeLayout mLayout;

    private EditText userInput;
    private String currentUserId, caption, msg;



    private DatabaseReference PostsRef;
    private StorageReference TestPostStorage;
    private RelativeLayout dragLayout;
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params;
    private Uri imageUri;
    Bitmap bm;
    Boolean clicked = false;

    private final static int Gall_pick = 67;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_canvas_test);


        currentUserId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();



        mLayout = findViewById(R.id.imgv);


        Post = findViewById(R.id.post);
        selectStory = findViewById(R.id.select);
        showet =  findViewById(R.id.editshow);
        showet.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        dragLayout = findViewById(R.id.drag);
        dragLayout.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());


        dragLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                switch (motionEvent.getAction()){
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        int x = (int) motionEvent.getX();
                        int y = (int) motionEvent.getY();
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        x = (int) motionEvent.getX();
                        y = (int) motionEvent.getY();
                        break;

                }
                return true;
            }
        });


        PostsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("CanvasTestPosts");
        TestPostStorage  = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("CTPStorage");

        selectStory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                OpenGallere();
            }
        });


       showet.setOnClickListener(new MyButtonClickListener());
       Post.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
               SendToDb();
           }
       });



    }

    public class CustomEdittext extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
    {

        Paint paint;

        public CustomEdittext(Context context){
            super(context);
            init();


        }

        public CustomEdittext(Context context, AttributeSet attr){
            super(context, attr);

            init();

        }


        public void init(){


            paint = new Paint();

            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(4);
            paint.setTextSize(22);
            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);


        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
        {

            super.onDraw(canvas);

            canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), paint);

        }


    }
    public class MyDragListener implements View.OnDragListener
    {

        private RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params;

        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event)
        {
            View view = (View) event.getLocalState();


            switch(event.getAction())
            {
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:

                    params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
                    break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                    int x = (int) event.getX();
                    int y = (int) event.getY();

                    break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED :

                    break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION  :
                    x=  (int) event.getX();
                    y =  (int) event.getY();
                    break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED   :

                    break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:

                    x = (int) event.getX();
                    y = (int) event.getY();
                    params.leftMargin = x;
                    params.topMargin = y;

                    view.setLayoutParams(params);
                    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    break;
                default: break;
            }
            return true;
        }


    }





    private void SendToDb() {
        final String key = PostsRef.push().getKey();
        StorageReference filePath = TestPostStorage.child(key);


        Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mLayout.getWidth(), mLayout.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);

        Drawable bgDrawable = mLayout.getBackground();
        if (bgDrawable != null){
            bgDrawable.draw(canvas);


        } else {
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
            mLayout.draw(canvas);

        }


        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        returnedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 20, baos);
        byte[] dataToUpload = baos.toByteArray();
        UploadTask uploadTask = filePath.putBytes(dataToUpload);

        uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Uri imageUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

                finish();
                return;

            }
        });



    }



    private void OpenGallere() {
        Intent gIntent = new Intent();
        gIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        gIntent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(gIntent, Gall_pick);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == Gall_pick && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){
            imageUri = data.getData();

            try {
                bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), imageUri);
                selectStory.setImageBitmap(bm);
            } catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        showet.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        dragLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    }

    private class MyLongClickListener implements View.OnLongClickListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v)
        {

            ClipData dragdata = ClipData.newPlainText("","");

            View.DragShadowBuilder shdwbldr = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v);

            v.startDrag(dragdata, shdwbldr, v, 0);
            v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            return true;
        }
    }

    private class MyButtonClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ViewGroup rp = (ViewGroup)view.getParent();
            CustomEdittext edttext = new CustomEdittext(view.getContext());
            rp.addView(edttext);
            edttext.setOnLongClickListener(new MyLongClickListener()  );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to draw multiple views to a bitmap, call draw method of the parent viewGroup which holds all the views.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Sir. Kindly would you show with help of code the necessary parameters that I need to change to achieve that

Comment: You called `mLayout.draw(canvas)`. Here mLayout is the EditText right? If you want the bitmap all the views including the buttons, get the root view (RelativeLayout) and call `view.draw(canvas)`

Comment: Noted, I get your point. But actually, am using mLayout as the rootview since I wouldnt want the post button to be included in the bitmap. Thats why Ive placed mLayout above the post button. Picture it this way, mLayout is the relative Layout where I want to draw the image picked from the user gallery,  the edittext in whichever position it will be after drag; then convert this to a bitmap and upload it to the database.

Comment: What I want stored in the storage should look as if i took a screenshot of mLayout, if you get my point.

Comment: You're converting the view(R.id.imgv) to bitmap right? Place your image and EditText within this viewGroup and then draw it. The `mLayout` will have only two children - EditText and Picture selected by the user.

Comment: WOW! Thanks a lot Sir! Simple but worked like a charm..much appreciated!